# How to specify the permissions of the directories that are generated by a Hadoop MapReduce job?

Tags: hadoop, permissions

When I run a Hadoop MapReduce job, all the directories that were generated use 'rwxr_xr_x' as the permissions. I would like to change them to 'rwxrwxrwx', how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hadoop fs -chmod 777 your/directory` to change it after the fact. Or create the directories before you run the job, and set their permissions accordingly. You might also be able to set the `dfs.umask` value, which will govern the permissions directories are created with.

See http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/hdfs_permissions_guide.html